# How can I get Text property to initialize to the objects name at design time?

Tags: c#, properties, attributes, custom-controls

When you add a label to the form from the toolbox, its text defaults to the item's name (`label1`, `label2`, etc). How can I make this happen with a custom control? So far, I have the following, which allows me to change the text through the property window:

```
private string _text;

[BrowsableAttribute(true)]
public override string Text
{
    get { return _text; }
    set
    {
        _text = value;
        lblID.Text = _text;
    }
}
```

---

Apparently the above code works as is, but I'm not sure why. Does `Text` default to the object's name automatically? The question still stands for other properties which don't override `Text`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the `Text` property is automatically set to the objects name when you inherit from `UserControl`. The following code works:

```
public partial class CustomControl: UserControl
{
    public string Extension { get; set; }

    private string _text;

    [BrowsableAttribute(true)] // Initializes to "customControlN"
    public override string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set { _text = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is because you are using the default Designer, which does that to the Text property. Almost all controls use the default Designer (or a subclass of it). If you disassemble the Label class you will see at the top:  `Designer("System.Windows.Forms.Design.LabelDesigner, System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")`, the LabelDesigner class subclasses `ControlDesigner`, it is ControlDesigner that is working with the Text property.

Answer (score 0):

```
private string _text = "default value"
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into `System.ComponentModel.DefaultValueAttribute`

Comment: Label's ability to do "label1", "label2" is handled through its designer. You can get info on that here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/813808